# Multiple input php array in wordpress plugin

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

In a wordpress plugin I use an array to export meta fields to csv.

The array looks like this:

```
    $export_data_mapping = [
            "meta_1" => "participant_last_name",
            "meta_2" => "participant_first_name",
            "meta_3"=> "participant_birthdate",
            "meta_4" => "participant_current_club",
];
```

Sometimes the value of "meta_1" is empty, and will be replaced by another metafield, called "meta_2". What I need to accomplish is that when "meta_1" is empty, it is replaced by "meta_2".

I tried this the following, but it didnt work:

```
$export_data_mapping = [
        "meta_1", "meta_2" => "participant_last_name",
        "meta_2" => "participant_first_name",
        "meta_3"=> "participant_birthdate",
        "meta_4" => "participant_current_club",
```

];

Anyone got the answer?

Comment: Your question is unclear and needs more explanation what you are trying to achieve. Edit it.

Comment: You are right, I made it more clear now.

Comment: So you post it a first time and it gets closed because it has already been answered, So you start another one?

Answer (score 0):

This is how it should be done.

```php
$export_data_mapping = [
    "meta_1" => "",
    "meta_2" => "participant_first_name",
    "meta_3"=> "participant_birthdate",
    "meta_4" => "participant_current_club",
];

foreach ($export_data_mapping as $key => $value) {
    // Check if its empty.
    if ($value == '') {

        // Find which meta_?? is it.
        $meta_number = intval(substr($key, -1));

        // Get the next meta by adding 1
        $new_key = 'meta_' . strval($meta_number + 1);

        // Check if the next meta exist or not, in case the empty meta is last we can't set it.
        if (array_key_exists($new_key, $export_data_mapping)) {
            // Make the metas value as the next metas.
            $export_data_mapping[$key] = $export_data_mapping[$new_key];
        }
    }
}

var_dump($export_data_mapping);
```

I have added comments to explain what each line does. Tested and works.